# Simplest C compiler & editor for Windows?

Tags: c, windows, vim, compiler-construction, ide

I want to develop C on Windows, but I really like just using vim and gcc to compile on Linux. Is there an IDE for Windows that is as simple?

I just want an editor with numbered lines, syntax highlighting, and a compile/run/build button that is all! (I am very new to C)

Or is there a way I have get Vim for Windows to compile C?

Thanks a lot

Solution: Set up MinGW, then GVim so I can jsut pen up vim and run :make to compile : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for a compiler, I would recommend MinGW.

Answer (score 2):

you can use gVim on windows,  and you can get it to compile using either Microsofts compiler or others.

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) for Windows has a vim mode.

Otherwise you can use cygwin vim in Windows.

Comment: Any idea how to compile C from Sublime Text 2?